# M. Hartl | RoR 4 Tutorial | RSpec Undefined Method 'visit' Chapter 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to follow the [tutorial here](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-TDD) and I've been following directions closely, I've had no real issues up until here.

This is my test failure. I'm new, please let me know what other files you'd like to see. Many thanks in advance.

**spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'capybara'
    RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

---

**static_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Static pages" do
  describe "Home page" do
  it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')

    end
  end
end
```

---

**test output**

```
MantisPowerBook:sample_app mantis$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb 

F

Failures:

  1) Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007f9e54301228>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.0005 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:4 # Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your spec_helper.rb file to

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"
end
```

After that your spec will fail for the right reasons

As far as i can tell the error was because you had

> config.include(CapyBara::DSL)

rather than

> config.include Capybara::DSL

Comment: I changed the folder from `spec/requests` to `spec/features` -- this didn't work. It produced: `MantisPowerBook:sample_app mantis$ rspec spec/
F

Failures:

  1) Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     ArgumentError:
       rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given
     # ./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00067 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Comment: adding `:type => :request` without changing the folder name produced the same, initial error.

Comment: This is the error I get after trying your edited suggestion `MantisPowerBook:sample_app mantis$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb 
/Users/mantis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:8:in `<class:Template>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Autoload (NameError)mantis`

Comment: Any chance you can throw your code up into a repo somewhere?

Comment: Yes. I re-made the app and this is my current problem ... http://pastebin.com/AfF2eUB1 and my repo ... https://github.com/m-antis/sample_app

Comment: I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 btw